# OpenCV SIFT out of memory error

Tags: c++, opencv, out-of-memory, sift

I am using a SIFT as a feature detector in a program, creating it with the default options:

```
cv::SiftFeatureDetector detector;
```

When I use the detection function (detector.detect( image, keypoints );) it throws me the an out of memory error:

> OpenCV Error: Insufficient memory (Failed to allocate 100663300 bytes)
>   in OutOfMemoryError

Anyone has an idea from where this error comes and how to solve it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How big is the image that you are using? Your error mentiones about 90mb of data that needs to be allocated.

Comment: Do you solve it? I have the same problem.

Comment: No, I think I read somewhere there was an error with the code, maybe now it is solved.